# When adding objects to this arraylist, they all become identical

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public void fillWith(TileEntity tile){
    for(int i = 0; i < this.height; i++){//for every x and y value
        for(int j = 0; j < this.width; j++){
            tile.x = j;
            tile.y = i;
            this.tiles.add(tile);
        }
    }
}
```

Okay so the above code is supposed to fill the level with a TileEntity tile. When I print out the x and y coords before the line "this.tiles.add(tile)", each tile has different coords. But when I print out the x and y coords of all of the tiles in the ArrayList "tiles", every single one is (9,9). They are all identical to the very last tile added to the arraylist. Thanks!

Comment: Us a debugger. It helps

Comment: how is the object tile declared?

Comment: Turbo- The object tile is declared as a class that inherits the abstract class TileEntity

Answer (score 7):

You keep adding the same object in your for-loop.

If you want to add different objects, you will need to create new instances using for example `new TileEntity()`.

```
public void fillWith(){
    TileEntity tile;
    for(int i = 0; i < this.height; i++){//for every x and y value
        for(int j = 0; j < this.width; j++){
            tile = new TileEntity();
            tile.x = j;
            tile.y = i;
            this.tiles.add(tile);
        }
    }
}
```

You are right that, in your code example, the values change every time you are in the loop, but because `tile` points to the same object every iteration, you will only change the `x` and `y` values *within* that object. (Java will not create a new object for you when you change `x` and/or `y`). When you add `tile` to the array `this.tiles`, it will `reference` the object you add - it will not make a copy of it.

All in all, `tile` *and* every object in your array will point to the same single instance of `TileEntity`.

Comment: But the values of the object change each time?

Comment: You add the same object to each position in the array.  Each time you change .x and .y you change it for all positions of the array.  You need to create a new instance of the object at the beginning of your 2nd for loop.  tile = new TileEntity();

Comment: But TileEntity is abstract

Comment: Then 'new TileEntity()' will not work - you will need to create one of the concrete sublasses. Example 'new TileEntityImplementation()'.

Answer (score 1):

You've succeeded in adding the same `tile` to the `ArrayList` 100 times.  There's still only one object here, so the last update "wins": `x = 9` and `y = 9`.

If you want different values, then you must add 100 *different* tile objects, each with their own distinct values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create  new tile object each time in the loop,otherwise each time the existed tile pbject changes and remains with the last inserted values.

```
 for(int j = 0; j < this.width; j++){
            tile= new TileEntity();
            tile.x = j;
            tile.y = i;
            this.tiles.add(tile);
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that TileEntity is abstract

Comment: @user2155333 So how you are receiving tile object ?? Can you show how you are calling that method ?